# Компиляция C в проекте С++

Tags: c++, c

Как можно скомпилировать или интегрировать .c в c++ проект?

Comment: Да так же, как и c++. Непонятно, конкретизируйте ваш вопрос, что не получается?

Comment: Толькоесли он на стандарте C89.

Comment: `gcc -c f.c` ; `g++ -c g.cpp` ; `g++ f.o g.o -o main`

Comment: А зачем? Перепишите на плюсах, там не так много придётся фактически менять для этого. Причём, компилятор поймёт вообще абсолютно всё, а если даже и не совсем так, то это выявляется тестами, тестить же так и так придётся весь проект. Кроме выделения и освобождения памяти, монструозного ввода-вывода и столь же монструозного преобразования из числового представления в текстовое и обратно весь остальной текст на голых сях даже человеком отлично читается на плюсах без понимания того, что это вовсе даже не они. Я ещё понимаю паскаль с плюсами надо именно смешивать, так как слишком различны.

Comment: Переписал на плюсы, но выдаёт ошибку
[C] До: https://i.imgur.com/LJJR6lf.png
[C++] После: https://i.imgur.com/8fc1lqT.png (уже с ошибкой)

Comment: надо `L"client.dll"`

Answer (score 4):

Принцип - предварительная компиляция разных языков в объектный файл. И потом эти объектные файлы можно уже собрать линковщиком. Язык C++  ушёл чуток от Си и чтобы имена функций и принципы передачи аргументов могли связаться как-то с Си функциями нужно заголовочный файл объявить со знаком `extern "C"`. Далее линковщик всё соберёт.

f.h

```c
int Cfun( int ) ;
```

f.c

```c
# include "f.h"
int Cfun( int i ){
  return i; 
}
```

g.hpp

```c++
int CPPfun( int ) ;
```

g.cpp

```c++
# include "g.hpp"
int CPPfun( int i ){
  return i; 
}
```

main.cpp

```c++
extern "C" {
# include "f.h"
}
# include "g.hpp"

int main(){
  int c = Cfun(0);
  int p = CPPfun(0);
}
```

Вот пример использования с компилятором **gcc**.

```
gcc -c f.c
g++ -c g.cpp main.cpp
g++ f.o g.o main.o -o main
```

Answer (score -1):

Компилируй всё в объектные файлы, создай файл link.ld , что писать в интернете смотри, и линкуй всё через линковщик ld (команда тоже в интернете, ищи линковка c и c++), компонуй из объектника в исполняемый и готово!

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).